# EWS - Ignoring certain folders during sync

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to sync emails in a mailbox that fit a certain criteria. Basically contained within certain folders.

Due to the nature of the app, I need the connection to be permanently open, so the mailbox will be synchronised, and a streaming subscription to certain folders will be opened.

My problem is that I want to connect all "Email" folders (not Calendar/Tasks etc.), and only those that are standard ones. i.e. not "Sent Items", "Deleted Items", "Drafts" etc.

The root folder i'm synchronising is:

```
WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot
```

And from that I am able to filter out "Email" folders by using :

```
Folder.FolderClass == "IPF.Note"
```

> *Note: Not sure this is the best way, but one thing at a time!*

So this returns good list of email folders, but still contains "Deleted Items" etc... I need to filter these out. An obvious option might be to filter by [Folder.DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.displayname(v=exchg.80).aspx), but due to the nice open nature of Exchange, users are able to legitimately create folders with the same name. I still want to access those.

Any ideas?

Comment: For what version of Exchange ? On 2013 it returns a WellKnownFolder https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.wellknownfoldername%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx property which you can use to tell if a folder is one of the Default folders or user created.

Comment: @GlenScales I'm not seeing the WellKnownFolder property come back by default from Outlook 365's EWS. Are you requesting an extra property to get it? If so, which one?

Comment: FolderSchema.WellKnownFolderName is the property you should be requesting although it should come back with the FirstClass properties. If you not seeing I would say you Server Request version is wrong you need to make sure you have set this to 2013 or up. If you use 2010 it won't be returned.